# Is it good praticse to use setTimeout() for a "session"

Tags: javascript

I want to use setTimeout to alert the user after 60 minutes "Your session has expired". After that I would like to execute some business logic with ajax and redirect him to the start page. Is this a good praticse?

Comment: setTimeout is for calling a function or making a change after a function was called.

Comment: Works, but if the user can interact with the server too, make sure to validate on the server as well, since you can't trust anything the client does

Comment: If that's your *only* mechanism to expire the session, the user is able to suppress it. The session should expire regardless server-side, but you may use a client-side alarm to inform the user about it.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "good practice". Too many things can go wrong. Somebody simply refreshing the site gives them extra 60 minutes.

Comment: It would be better to store the expected end time in a cookie or localstorage. And use a setInterval to frequently check if the specified time has passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the risk of getting out of sync here between client and server session timeout. As the session timeout should be reset on every request to the server, you will have to make sure the timeout on the client is also reset. Easy if there are only full page requests in your application but hard if you do ajax calls as I assume.

Another concern is the business logic with ajax execution you mention. If the session has expired, no business logic execution on the server for this user should be allowed any more to my understanding.

How about simply waiting until the user triggers the next action on the UI where he would need to be authorized and then tell him about the expired session and request a re-login? You could even do this with ajax and in a modal popup to stay on the screen the user currently uses. This way the user would not loose any data he currently entered/edited when his session expired.

What do you think?